# Anyone know an Actionscript 3 pretty printing library for JSON data?

Tags: json, actionscript

In Adobe Flex / Actionscript 3, I would love to pretty print my JSON data to a TextArea. Any libraries out there? A decent search turned up no results. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's a decent library available from http://maccherone.com/larry/projects/a-pretty-json-encoder-for-actionscript-3-as3/

The syntax for using it is more-or-less the same as if you were using the normal JSON libraries.

In the 'normal' Adobe as3corelib class you'd use `JSON.encode(object)`, whereas with this library you add an extra Boolean parameter to get a Pretty-printed output: `JSON.encode(object, true)`